# Trying To Make The Code Platform Independent - Reading SQL File From PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hello everyone and here's the code which reads .sql file and stores each query in an array element. In my .sql file there are various statement like CREATE TABLE, DROP, INSERT

```
$fileLines = file('alltables.sql');

$templine = '';
foreach ($fileLines as $line)
{
    // Skip it if it's a comment
    if (substr($line, 0, 2) == '--' || $line == '')
    continue;

    // Add this line to the current segment
    $templine .= $line;

    // If it has a semicolon at the end, it's the end of the query
    if (substr(trim($line), -1, 1) == ';')
{
    // Perform the query
    $queries[] = $templine;
    // Reset temp variable to empty
    $templine = '';
}
}

// Here I further process $queries var
```

It works fine under windows platform but I'm not sure that whether it will work on linux server or not so I want you please look at the code and let me know should I need to alter the code something like (\t\r\0 \x0B) to handle new line and carriage return for different platforms :

```
$tmp=str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $line);
$tmp=str_replace("\r", "\n", $line);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not safe to do it your way, since there may also be \r or \n in a SQL statement (e.g. a long TEXT with many lines).

If you're sure there aren't case like that, I'd suggest you to use [trim()](http://www.php.net/trim) instead of [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/str_replace). It'll remove all spaces and EOL at the end of each lines.

```
<?php

$tmp = trim($line);

?>
```

You may also specify to ONLY REMOVE EOL (both "\r\n" and "\n") like this:

```
<?php

$tmp = trim($line, "\r\n");

?>
```

Comment: hmm, you're right there are many tables which have text datatype field.  Would you tell me exactly where should I write your recommended code. Secondly and most important what do you say about the question which I initially asked about making the code platform independent.

Comment: My code meant to replace your str_replace() lines. But if you have text datatype, my code doesn't solve your problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use existing SQL parser library.

For example:

- http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/